# selecionar dados de uma procedure de sql server em C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

fiz uma procedure que pega todos os dados de todas as colunas da minha tabela sql de interesse, na minha aplicação asp em c# consigo colocar todas as linhas numa lista ,mas eu preciso refinar essa busca pegando somente todos os dados de uma coluna só. Pesquisei um pouco e vi que com expressões Lambda isso é possível, mas não entendi como implementar. Alguma ajuda?

Comment: Envie a estrutura da classe da lista. Ex. List<ClasseDaLista>. Preciso da estrutura da ClasseDaLista para montar o linq

Comment: E um o resultado tabular de sua procedure tbm, não precisa incluir os valores, apenas a estrutura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supondo que a `Lista<>` seja uma `Lista<Pessoas> ListaDePessoas()`, e você tem todas as pessoas de acordo com retorno da sua Procedure. Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio sua Tabela tem os Campo (ID, Nome, Nascimento, etc), Logicamente, cada objeto Pessoa em sua Lista tem uma propriedade referindo-se a cada Coluna.

Estou supondo que vc queira reunir todos os registros da coluna que representa o Nome de cada pessoa.

`using System.Collections.Generic;`//-> responsável por fornecer o tipo `List<>`

Acreditando que sua lista esta preenchida com todas as Tuplas desejadas:
você pode armazenar a coluna desejada em outra lista, uma matriz ou direto em um componente.

irei ultilizar uma `List<>` para armazenar essa coluna desejada.

```
List<string> ListaNomes = new List<string>();

ListaDePessoas.ForEach(delgate (Pessoas pessoa))
   ListaNomes.add(pessoa.Nome);
);
```

Espero ter ajudo, mesmo com pouco informação.